# how to hide the extra details?

Tags: java, maven

I'm new to java. I was wondering that how can I hide the extra details whenever I run a class or a whole project. I only want to see "hello world" not the rest of the detail, if it's possible.

```
cd /home/hamza/NetBeansProjects/testing; JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 /home/hamza/netbeans/java/maven/bin/mvn "-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath application.testing.hello" -Dexec.executable=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Dexec.classpathScope=runtime process-classes org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building testing 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ testing ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/hamza/NetBeansProjects/testing/src/main/resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ testing ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ testing ---
hello world
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.342 s
Finished at: 2020-02-29T21:54:11+05:00
Final Memory: 9M/37M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: How are you running the application. form log i can see that you are using maven to run your application the extra logs are generated by maven.

Comment: yes i'm running the application through maven. On the last netbeans version there was no maven, so this is new for me and confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the `mvn` command using `--quiet` or `-q` parameter:

```
mvn --quiet ...
```

or

```
mvn -q ... ...
```

If you want to suppress the display of transfer progress when downloading or uploading, use `--no-transfer-progress` or `-ntp`:

```
mvn --no-transfer-progress ....
```

or

```
mvn -ntp ... ....
```

Check [here](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-embedder/cli.html) for reference.

Click the **Maven Settings** button shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Type **-q** in the box shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Press **OK** button and then run your class.

Comment: @HamzaZahirKhan - I have added screenshots. I hope, it helps. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt.